# Dockerize .net core appplication that connect to non-docker oracle database

Tags: oracle, .net-core, dockerfile

I am developing an application based on .NET Core (3.1) which connect to a oracle database.
My development machine running Windows and it is running correctly. now I need to dockerize this application.

I use this package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.90

```
string ConnStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostIP)(PORT = port))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = name)));User ID=username;Password=password;";
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
OraConn = new OracleConnection(ConnStr);
OraConn.Open();
```

I don't know how can I edit my Dockerfile to achieve this.

My dockerfile :

```
FROM dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.301
WORKDIR /app

FROM dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.301

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["GetMyData/GetMyData.csproj", "GetMyData/"]
COPY ["GetMyData/.","GetMyData/"]


RUN dotnet restore "GetMyData/GetMyData.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/GetMyData"

RUN dotnet build "GetMyData.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GetMyData.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GetMyData.dll"]
```

I got this error when I run the container :

> Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse
> connect string

Comment: so, you run the docker container locally and it's not working?

Comment: yes, I got this error "Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string"

Comment: is your connection string in appsettings.json or appsettings.env.json? If you use env json setting, make sure you have `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env passed in for docker container run.

Comment: I identify the connection string in the code, please see ConnStr in above code.
also I try it  as env_variable but I got the same error.
should I install oracle_clinet on my container, or not related??

Comment: ah try exposing port 80 and 443 in dockerfile